# Prettified way to read mail in linux command line?

Tags: linux, email, sendmail

I was wondering if there is a command-line way to read the stuff that is in `/var/mail/$USER` in an attractive way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Alpine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpine_%28email_client%29)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup, mutt

mutt -f /var/mail/$USER

Example:
[image]